# Сброс пароля grandstream 1625?

Tags: администрирование, sip, voip, телефония

Есть удаленный офис с телефонами grandstream 1625. Один из телефонов не доступен по web и не отвечает на icmp. На шлюзе я вижу мак и арп этого телефона. Попросил админа по месту сбросить телефон, но там стоит админский пароль который никто не помнит (ставил админ который был до меня). В связи с этим вопрос, есть ли какая-нибудь возможнось его привести в чувства, либо сбросить в дефолт, прошу помощи у знающих. Спасибо!

Comment: Сильно сомневаюсь, что по такой узкой области тут есть спецы. В оф. саппорт не пробовал обратиться?

Comment: Привет. Этот пост создавался от бессилия. Да, думаю нужно обращаться в саппорт.